# Matlab View Entire Command Window

Tags: arrays, matlab

I am trying to display a large array into the command window but it gets truncated because the command window only shows so many lines.  Is there a way to change the settings so that it shows everything printed in the command window?

I am currently calling the display like so:

```
disp(array);
```

This variable is a temporary one in a function so it does not get saved into the workspace variables, so thats why I am looking for a printing alternative.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better way would be to save it in to a text file using [fprintf()](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/fprintf.html) instead of cluttering up your command window.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [`dlmwrite`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/techdoc/ref/dlmwrite.html) as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to view the entire array you could always write it out to a file.

Answer (score 1):

I personally would use FPRINTF as already stated, but just for your information, you can use the [DIARY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/diary.html) command to output all command window output to a file. This will not be truncated.